R plot multiple lines grouping data
I have the following dataset :
         date prmd   N Tx
 1: 2023-10-31  UAE 102889
 2: 2023-10-31   UB  15183
 3: 2023-11-30   TX      2
 4: 2023-11-30  UAE  94110
 5: 2023-11-30   UB  15339
 6: 2023-12-31   TX     67
 7: 2023-12-31  UAE  90417
 8: 2023-12-31   UB  16556
 9: 2024-01-31   TX     44
10: 2024-01-31  UAE  86732
11: 2024-01-31   UB  16572
12: 2024-02-29   TX     34
13: 2024-02-29  UAE  84257
14: 2024-02-29   UB  15745

I'd like to plot in R using ggplot2 3 lines, 1 for each prmd (i.e. UB, TX, UAE) where x=date and y='N Tx'.
I tried using group/color but couldn't succeed.
I'd like the code to be sort of general, i.e. cover cases where more categorical values exist as prmd (i.e. not for just 3 lines).
Thanks in advance

It would be easier to help you if you provide a minimal reproducible example including a minimal but complete example code and a snippet of your input data best shared using dput(). This said, perhaps the issue is simply that you wrapped you non-syntactically valid variable name aka "N Tx" in quotes instead of back-ticks.

Thanks a lot. Actually it was something similar to what you suggested. I had to use [[ ]] for the variable I use that refers to "prmd". But your hint showed me the way. Cheers
